# I am trying to multiply padding with for loop in sass but its not happening

Tags: compass-sass

With the help of @for loop in SASS I want to apply padding (pixel unit) to my list by multiplying for every level but its giving me raw output. My SASS code is :

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
.chapter-summary  {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        padding-bottom: (10px) * #{$i};
    }
}
```

}

and its giving me following output :

```
.chapter-summary:nth-child(1) {
  padding-bottom: 10px * 1;
}

.chapter-summary:nth-child(2) {
  padding-bottom: 10px * 2;
}

.chapter-summary:nth-child(3) {
  padding-bottom: 10px * 3;
}

.chapter-summary:nth-child(4) {
  padding-bottom: 10px * 4;
}

.chapter-summary:nth-child(5) {
  padding-bottom: 10px * 5;
}
```

Need a solution

Answer (score 3):

Ok guyz I got the solution and that is as following :

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
    .chapter-summary  {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            padding-bottom: #{$i * 10px};
        }
    }
}
```